# There is a way to transfer / mint tokens without ERC20 owner approval method?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, erc20, openzeppelin

I trying to understand how crowdsale work in this way of buying tokens.

The part of send ether to a contract is ok, but the part of token transfer is still dark for me.

I have a ERC20Mintable token, in the latest version of openzeppelin.

My crowdsale contract will have thousands and thousands of buyers. In most tutorials, they teach transfering tokens with transferFrom, but that requires the approval of ERC20 owner correct ? Is what most of tutorials show. I can mint either, probably because only owner can mint tokens.
My question is: there is a method that users can buy tokens without any action of the ERC20 owner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Owner approval is needed for `transferFrom` function. Because with this function you are allowing third-party account transfer from your account to someone.

Let's say I want to transfer token from your account to my brother's account. To be able to do this, you have to give permission first and this permission is stored in a mapping. If you allow me to transfer a specific amount from your account, you first add my account into this mapping

```
    // my address is allowed to transfer token to other address
    mapping(address=>mapping(address=>uint256)) allowed;
```

with `approve` function.

```
 function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public override returns (bool success){
            // you are calling this. so you are the msg.sender
            // first we are checking if you have enough token to be transferred
            require(tokenBalances[msg.sender]>=_value,"insufficient token");
            // then you register my account with the _value
            allowed[msg.sender][_spender]=_value;
            // if in the future there is a dispute, we can check those events for verification
            emit Approval(msg.sender,_spender,_value);
            return true;
        }
```

This where owner approval used. If you want to transfer money from your account to another account, you use the `transfer` function:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public override returns (bool success){
        require(tokenBalances[msg.sender]>=_value,"you do not have enough tokens");
        tokenBalances[msg.sender]-=_value;
        tokenBalances[_to]+=_value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender,_to,_value);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also finding this solution for me but didn't find any proper solution.

however find a solution for now.
create a function that is payable and pass amount(how much buyer buy) and make a keccak hash with (sender , value and amount) and store in a map and send transfer receive eth to _admin address.

```
function swapEthToVs(uint256 amount) public payable returns (bytes32) {
    require(_admin != _msgSender(),"You Cannot Buy this Coin At this moment");
    bytes32 kHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.value,amount,_msgSender()));
    swapHash[_origin()] = kHash;
    payable(address(_admin)).transfer(msg.value);
    return kHash;
}
```

then create api that take (sender , amount ,contractOwner) and call another function with contractOwnerSigner

```
function verifySwapHash(uint256 eth,address to,uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
    require(swapHash[to] == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(eth, amount, to)),"Invalid hash no trace found");
    transfer(to, amount);
    delete swapHash[to];
    return true;
}
```

I know this is risky but i didn't found any solution. if you found any solution please describe solution.